# Optimize unused space in RAID5 due to bigger HDD in spare parts change

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, raid5, sata, hp-smart-array

I have started with `3x250 GB SATA` array, but the old HDDs failed one by one and when the spare parts came they where bigger disk inside and I recently ended up with 3 HDDs of `500 GB`.

[image]

[image]

I see reported unused space 698.6GB, can I optimize the present configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this is an easy process...

Once the rebuild is done, you can either use the "Unused Space" to create another **Logical Drive** (e.g. *Logical Drive 3*), or you can **Extend** Logical Drive 2 to utilize the extra space.

Once this is done, you'll see a larger block device available to your operating system.

- If this is Windows, the free space will be available and you'll need to extend it in the Disk Management console.
- If this is Linux, you'll need to make fdisk partition changes (or LVM craziness) in order to use the new space.

Also see: [Smart Array P212 Raid controller on SBS 2008 ProLiant G6](https://serverfault.com/questions/418093/p212-raid-controller-on-sbs-2008-proliant-g6/418103#418103)